# Casting operator issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, casting, migration

```
A* pa = dynamic_cast<A*>(reinterpret_cast<A*>(pb));
```

where `pb` is `void` pointer
so this gives wrong value into `pa`, sometime it gives `NULL` or sometimes not `NULL`

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is a no-op here. You give it an `A*` pointer, it will just return it unchanged. The result is `NULL` if `pb` is `NULL`, and not `NULL` if `pb` is not `NULL`. To the extent there is a problem, it lies in the code not shown. Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: @Igor Good point.

Comment: Basically code is migrating from vc++ 6.0 to visual studio 2015 , so there is any change in casting?

Comment: @SSW no, there didn't change anything in unsafeties of using `reinterpret_cast<T>()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok then there is some mismatch behaviour shows in vc++ 6.0 and visual studio 2015.Because some functionalities not working in vs 2015 though which was worked into vc++ 6.0

Comment: I get the impression you're having a problem in your ported code overall, and have concluded that there's a problem with this specific line of code. Exactly why do you suspect this specific line of code is in error? A `void` pointer can be NULL or not NULL, so the comment doesn't really explain what's wrong.

Comment: @lurker Actually fuctionality not work it gives runtime issue or some mismatch behaviour